# When $(x+y+z)^{5} $ is multiplied it gives a formula $\sum_{i,j,k} c_{i,j,k}x^{i}y^{j}z^{k}$. How to find $c_{5,0,0}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When $(x+y+z)^{5} $ is multiplied it gives a formula $\sum_{i,j,k} c_{i,j,k}x^{i}y^{j}z^{k}$. I need to find $c_{5,0,0}$ or $c_{1,1,3}$ or $c_{3,3,3}$. I only need to see a pattern for one because i don't know where to begin.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of  the expansion of  $(x+y+z)^5$  as choosing one element out of $\{x,y,z\}$ five times where the order doesn't matter. For example choosing $(\color{red}{x}+y+z)(\color{red}{x}+y+z)(\color{red}{x}+y+z)(\color{red}{x}+y+z)(\color{red}{x}+y+z)$ gets you $x^5$, note that this is the only possible way to get $x^5$. Note that if there exists a term $x^ay^bz^c$ in the expansion then $a+b+c=5$  (why?).

This is a combinatorics question. How many sequences of zeroes and ones have exactly n zeroes and m ones? If you label the balls $1,2\dotsb n+m$ you can put them in order in $(n+m)!$ ways but if you do that you'll have repeated sequences because you could have permuted the ones among themselves in $m!$ ways, same for zeroes. So you counted every valid sequence exactly $n!m!$ times which means the answer to the question is $\frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}$. How can this be generalised to sequences of zeroes, ones, twos...?

Answer (score 1):

You have five factors, $x+y+z$.  For each of the final terms, you pick one of the three terms from each of the five factors.
For example, when you look for $x^3yz$ terms.  You pick an $x$ from three of the five factors, a $y$ from another factor, and a $z$ from the last.  For example, you could pick $x$ from factors 1,4,5; a y from factor 2 and a z from factor 3.
In this case, I picked the capital letters from $$(X+y+z)(x+Y+z)(x+y+Z)(X+y+z)(X+y+z)$$
How many ways can you do that?